# hadoop ApplicationMaster ask for resource

Tags: hadoop, resources, allocation

I want to know when AM apply for resource from RM, how does AM know to ask for what amount resource? I have tried to read the code, but it is hard for me to find the answers. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ApplicationMaster can request whatever it feels like. It is up to the ResourceManager to decide what to actually grant it. In many cases you specify how much it should request. E.g. in `spark-submit --driver-memory 5G`

Comment: Thanks. If I submit MapReduce application, and set the configuration mapreduce.map.memory.mb=1024 and 10 map tasks, AM will apply for <10 containers, each contain represent 1GB memory> ?

Comment: Yep! Assuming you mean MR2. MR1 does not work with YARN and handles its own resource management.